# Ignore other .gitignore files than the one in root

Tags: gitignore

**My Actual Question**

I would like that only the `.gitignore` file in the root of my directory structure ignore files, i.e, the `.gitignore` files in subdirectories shouldn't ignore files.

**To be clear**

I don't want to gitignore other `.gitignore` files. I want them to be commited to git but I don't want them to gitignore other files.

**Specific use-case**

Let's say I want to commit a boilerplate project structure to git. Let's say the project structure looks like this:

```
project-root/
│
├── boilerplate/
│   ├──directory/
│   ├──some-other-directory/
│   ├──.env
└── └──.gitignore // Has a line ".env" which will ignore the .env file in this directory 
│
├── boilerplate2/
│   ├──directory/
│   ├──some-other-directory/
│   ├──.env
└── └──.gitignore
│
└── .gitignore // The .gitignore in root
```

Now the `.gitignore` file in `boilerplate` directory will gitignore `.env` which I don't want. How can I stop nested `.gitignore` files from taking action?

**What I tried?**

I tried the negation (`!`) operator in the main `.gitignore` file. For the sample structure above, it's equivalent to `!boilerplate/.env`. The `.gitignore` in root simply doesn't have any power over the `.gitignore` file in the specified directory. It doesn't override it. Why does it work like that? Is there a workaround?

**Edit**:

[VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71391591/16881932) suggests to automate that using scripts, but that's not the question. The question is, how to do that using only `.gitignore`, if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

> Now the .gitignore file in boilerplate directory will gitignore .env which I don't want.

It will not.

If `boilerplate/.env` is already added (`git add --force`) and committed, any change to that particular `.env` file would still be detected, not ignored.

The OP adds:

> But when I do git status, git ignores boilerplate/.env due to boilerplate/.gitignore (which isn't commited either)

Then, yes, it will ignore all `.env`, unless they are themselves versions.

---

> The `.gitignore` in root simply doesn't have any power over the `.gitignore` file in the specified directory.
> It doesn't override it.

That follows the [precedence rules for a `.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> Patterns read from a `.gitignore` file in the same directory as the path, or in any parent directory (up to the top-level of the working tree), **with patterns in the higher level files being overridden by those in lower level files down to the directory containing the file**.

---

In your case, I would:

- keep the `.env` rule
- version only `.env.tpl` template files with default initial value
- add a `.gitattributes` file with a smudge [content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10571580/6309) script declaration for `*.tpl`

That smudge script (for instance, 'script_tpl', which can be versioned as well) would be a bash script (which does work even on Windows, since Git for Windows comes with `bash.exe`):

```
#!/bin/bash

file="${f%.tpl}" # ex: .env.tpl => .env
if [[ ! "${file}" ]]; then cp "${f}" "${file}"; fi
```

I would add an `senv` script to be executed by any collaborator using a local cloned of the repository, in order to register automatically the content filter driver. It would include:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$(readlink -f "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" )" && pwd )"
# assuming the smudge script is at the root of the repository
which script_tpl || export PATH=${PATH}:${DIR} 
git config --global filter.tpl.smudge 'script_tpl'
```

That way, any time you switch branch, the smudge script with check if `.env` does exist and, if not, will create one (which will be ignored by all the various `.gitignore` files)

Comment: Neither `.env` not `boilerplate/` is commited. Only the root `.gitignore` is commited. But when I do `git status`, git ignores `boilerplate/.env` due to `boilerplate/.gitignore` (which isn't commited either)

Comment: @StarkProgrammer OK. I have updated my answer to propose an alternative approach.

Comment: If I understand you right, the first thing you say is to rename `.env` to `.env.tpl` as a template file. Then you provide a script that creates a `.env.tpl` if it doesn't exist. This whole thing isn't needed if I rename the file, because `.gitignore` will not ignore `.env.tpl` anyway. Then I can rename the file to `.env`. But that defeats the purpose of question as it should relate to `How to do that using .gitignore`, and not `bash script`

Comment: @StarkProgrammer to create .env, not to create .env.tpl.